# Custom HTTP Header or cookies? how custom authentication/authorization helps in CSRF?

Tags: javascript, http, csrf

1. If someone can help me understand how a custom HTTP authorization header helps protect CSRF attack.
2. Also correct me if i'm wrong does it prevent replay attacks using fiddler also?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: This should be asked over on http://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: sure is there any means i can move it or i need to post a different question over there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When authentication is based on cookie, every fired request from the client will be authenticated. Whether it is a "good" - intended by application, or "bad - as a result of CSRF attack. Browser will always **blindly** add cookie to every request. When authentication is based, for instance, on bearer token attached to "Authenticate" header, the client has an ability to decide on which scenario to send authenticated request and on which to remain anonymous.

This, however, doesn't mean that you cannot intercept request using tools like Fiddler, grab the token from HTTP header and perform authenticated request from the same tool.

Comment: so what is the difference then using just a custom http header based token to cookie based authentication? still have same problem correct?

Comment: Again, in case of HTTP header client has a control when the request is authenticated and when it is not. This prevents certain types of attacks, on another hand this introduces other issues, for instance, client has a responsibility of storing authentication token.

Comment: Can i access the these custom headers from java script?

Comment: Here is an example using jQuery: `$.ajax('/api/some', : { 'Authenticate': 'Bearer: some_token_here' }});`

Comment: I'm still missing the point like if cookie is repeated by browser in every request and can be accessed by javascript. same can be done with custom headers so its just provide one more variable for someone to figure out to do CSRF? or something more to it. If these custom headers are not available to JavaScript then someone can't execute and steal my custom header which can be done to cookie easily?

Comment: Ok i think now i got it... i should provide a new CSRF token for every request so that it refreshes and can't be used or replayed by anyone.

Comment: Authentication and session cookies usually are marked with HttpOnly flag, meaning client doesn't have access to it, meaning every request will contain them, unless expired or removed by server. I highly recommend you to go over [OWASP recommendations](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81213/discussion-between-jenya-y-and-sumeet-kumar).